# javascript node.js read command line stream

Tags: node.js

i have a node.js script which uses npm commander to read args.

like `node a.js -a "hello" -b "100"`

but i have an issue when sending html data to this like

`node a.js -a "some Html content with double quotes and single quotes" -b "100"`

one option i can think is sending EOL like

```
node a.js -b "100" << EOL
some Html content with double quotes and single quotes
EOL
```

how do i read this in node.js (with commander : https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander )

Comment: Have a look at `process.stdin`, and/or module `readline` ;)

Comment: Why not storing the html content in a file?

Comment: this script will be called regularly, don't want to manage files and maintanence of the same.. deleteing etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) built-in node.js module this way:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
});

let html = ''

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    if (input === 'EOL')
        console.log('received html: ' + html)
    else
        html+= ' ' + input
});
```

call with `node a.js -b  "100"`, then enter your HTML, using as many lines as you want.
When typing EOL (in a single line), the program will consider that the HTML input has been fully provided.